# Uso de scale en bash

Tags: bash, shell

Estoy intentando imprimir por pantalla un vector asociativo con decimales pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo:

```
#!/bin/bash

cantidades="cantidades.csv"
line=20
declare -A sumaCantidad
declade -A media
declare -A numeroCantidades
for i in `seq 2 $line`
do
NOMBRE=`cat $cantidades | sort -n -k2 -t"," | head -n$i | tail -n1 | cut -d ',' -f4`
CANTID=`cat $cantidades | sort -n -k2 -t"," | head -n$i | tail -n1 | cut -d ',' -f5`
sumaCantidad[$NOMBRE]=$((sumaCantidad[$NOMBRE]+CANTID))
numeroCantidades[$NOMBRE]=$((numeroCantidades[$NOMBRE]+1))
done
for i in `seq 2 $line`
do
NOMBRE=`cat $cantidades | sort -n -k2 -t"," | head -n$i | tail -n1 | cut -d ',' -f4`
media[$NOMBRE]={sumaCantidades[$NOMBRE]}/${numeroCantidades[$NOMBRE]}
echo "$media[$NOMBRE]}"
done
```

Lo que ocurre es que al imprimir la media solo imprime el numero entero, sin decimales, y yo quiero que haga la operación con decimales. 
¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

El archivo tiene esta pinta

```
[...],[...],[...],NOMBRE,CANTIDAD

0,0,0,Juan,4

0,0,0,Juan, 7

0,0,0,Jose,10

0,0,0,Maria,4

0,0,0,Maria,6
```

etc

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir una muestra del archivo `cantidades.csv`?

Comment: has probado a mirar el comando awk? seguramente ganabas facilidad y podrías hacer mas cosas

Comment: @Spidvmp ¿entonces no se puede hacer de la forma que lo estoy haciendo?

Answer (score 3):

A tu comentario, imagino que quieres sumar por cada persona, cuantos valores y la media, si, se podría, pero creo que te complicas demasiado. El awk puede diferir dependiendo de la versión de Linux/UNIX. Yo le he hecho en Mac, así que si pruebas en ubuntu puede que tengas que cambiar algo. He recreado un fichero txt con unos datos y un fichero awk donde va el código

El txt donde estanos datos, se llama hola.txt

```
a:s:d:Pepe:4
a:s:d:Manolo:10
a:s:d:Pepe:12
a:s:d:Pepe:14
a:s:d:Maria:4
a:s:d:Manolo:23
```

el awk donde va el script que tiene que tratar ese fichero le he llamado src.awk

```
{
elem[$4] = 1
suma[$4] += $5
cant[$4]++
} END {
   print("Nombre\tSuma\tCant\tMedia")
   for (e in elem) {
      print(e, "\t", suma[e],"\t", cant[e],"\t",suma[e]/cant[e])
   }
}
```

y la ejecución:

```
awk -F: -f src.awk hola.txt
```

El awk lo que hace es ocuparse de abrir el fichero de los datos (hola.txt) lo lee linea a linea y a cada linea le aplica el script que he escrito en src.awk y se acabo. Con el $numero vas referenciandote a la columna que quieras, y ahi esta cada valor. 
Genero el array de elem para tener los nombres que van apareciendo, ya que van a ser el indice para guardar la suma y las veces que aparecen.
Mirate los parámetros -F para el separador de columnas y creo que con esto ganas mucha potencia para tratar un fichero de texto.

las 3 primeras columnas de hola.txt las he rellenado con algo que en principio no lo necesitas, un poco por seguir tu ejemplo

Espero que te haya servido

Comment: en lugar de hardcodear "\t" por todo, puedes definir OFS a "\t" y así es automático.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, funciona lo que me dices, pero yo quería saber como hacerlo para el código que he implementado.¿No hay ninguna forma de mostrar con decimales?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he encontrado, para que pueda operar con decimales se utitliza el comando "bc" de la siguiente manera:

```
for i in `seq 2 $line`
do
NOMBRE=`cat $cantidades | sort -n -k2 -t"," | head -n$i | tail -n1 | cut -d ',' -f4`
media[$NOMBRE]=$(echo "scale=2;${sumaCantidades[$NOMBRE]/$numeroCantidades[$NOMBRE]}" | bc)
echo "$media[$NOMBRE]}"
done
```